# Dictonary.Keys.Any output

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Dictionary containing a string as a key and MyClass as a Value.
I also have an array of strings. I am checking in an if-condition, if a certain string contains any of the known keys in the dictionary:

```
if (MyDictionary.Keys.Any(k => MyStringArray[i].Contains(k)))
```

The Problem I have is: I need the value of k for which the check is true. So I want to know, which of the keys is contained in the string. How can I do this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Any`, use `Where`:

```
var keys = MyDictionary.Keys.Where(k => MyStringArray[i].Contains(k)).ToList();

if (keys.Count > 0)
    // ...
```

Comment: Note the `.ToList()` is important, if you don't do that it would do the search twice, once to look up the count (with a `.Count()` or a `.Any()`) and once to use the items in the result.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer. If I wanted to get the coresponding value, do I have to run a second request to get value by key or is there a way to get the value right away, still checking for the key in the string?

Comment: `keys` is a list of all the keys in `MyDictionary` that matched to the given string. You can use them simply with something like `MyDictionary[keys[j]]`. If you're talking about the string, then it's still `MyStringArray[i]` as long as `i` hasn't changed.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you. Sorry, I can't upvote you yet, not enough rep. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this, you could also use `FirstOrDefault` and if the result is not null you have a match:

```
var foundKey = MyDictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => MyStringArray[i].Contains(k));
if(foundKey != null)
{

}
```

Comment: For some reason FirstOrDefault returns Type Char instead of string

Comment: @xxldoener can you should the code where your Dictionary is initialized?

Comment: @xxldoener It should return whatever type you are using for your dictionary's key. Incidentally, that type should be either `string` or `char`, otherwise `MyStringArray[i].Contains(k)` won't compile.